# Get current folder from Excel not working formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, directory

I'm trying to obtain the current forlder from the document with this formula in Excel:

```
=LEFT(CELL("Book1.xlsx"),SEARCH("\[",CELL("Book1.xlsx")))
```

But I'm getting an error `#VALUE!` I'm not sure why, some help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the full path with filename and sheet name you have to use like this:

```
=CELL("filename")
```

Output: `C:\Users\user\Desktop\sample\[example.xls]A Test Sheet`

To get the full path from the current file (previously saved)

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename"),FIND("[",CELL("filename"))-1)
```

Output: `C:\Users\user\Desktop\sample\`

[Reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-the-current-excel-file-name-path-or-worksheet-in-a-cell-186833c6-c899-4912-a14c-240c2eb51e0b)

Comment: You should include a cell reference in the CELL call (any cell in the workbook will do).  If you don't you'll get the path to whatever workbook is active when the formula recalculate, which may or may not be for the workbook containing the formula.  [See here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf) for more details

Comment: Also you can use `LET` to avoid repeating the `CELL` part of the  formula

Comment: So, formula becomes `=LET(fn,CELL("filename",A1),LEFT(fn,FIND("[",fn)-1))`

Comment: This formula will update everytime that I move the file to another directory?

Comment: @Eduardomaker so did you test it?